# How to have dynamic property name in responded Json based on the value of passed eventType

Tags: json, spring-boot, web-services, jackson

Request:  baseUrl/eventType/Sales/
In request url, eventType could be Sales, Claims, Receiving. On the basis of event Type field below id should be changed

"id": "123",
  "sales": [
    {
      "weekStartDate": "10-01-2020",
      "qty": 0
    }
  ],
  "node": 0
}

Comment: what did you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change a `json` first convert it to Javascript object by:

```
const obj = JSON.parse("your json string")
```

Then you can change object properties simply:

```
obj.id = newId
```

Finally convert back object to JSON:

```
const newJson = obj.stringify(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an existing annotation which would do the parsing for me. Finally I found it.

Solunion:

```
@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, List<NestedSale>> getProperties() {
  return properties;
}
```

@JsonAnyGetter is working well for my use case

I am getting this response:

```
{
"eventType": "Receiving",
  "Receiving": [
    {
      "weekStartDate": "10-01-2020",
      "qty": 0
    }
  ],
"node": 0 
}
```

Thanks to @Xaqron for your response.